# SharePoint Online & MS Flow

Tags: calendar, flow

I am currently using SharePoint Online through Office 365 and recently obtained MS Flow in my suite of apps. We have an existing SharePoint team site with an Out Of Office Calendar that already has a workflow integrated months before I arrived at this company. The calendar basically uses a pending/approved status on the calendar itself, and upon clicking on the pending/approved, I am redirected to a "Page not found" page.
What I'm trying to do is go into the workflow to observe the settings and see if there are perhaps any errors that could be fixed. When I look at the toolbar on any page, I can't find the Flow icon! All that's displayed are "New, upload, sync, Export to Excel, and horizontal ellipses." Is there a way I can add Flow to this toolbar?

Furthermore, when I go to workflow settings the message is, "This workflow cannot be customized from the browser. Use a SharePoint-compatible workflow editing tool, such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer, to edit this workflow." My supervisor has told me that the workflow was created by a contractor and that that contractor used MS Flow with the OOO Calendar. What can I do to edit the settings?

Comment: MS Flow and SharePoint Workflow are two different things. From your statement I guess a workflow is attached to the list instead of Flow. So you have to use SharePoint designer to access that workflow. Connet to your site in SharePoint designer and then go to Workflows section. In there you will find all the workflows of your site. Then edit the workflow from there.

Answer (score 0):

To edit this workflow you probably need SharePoint designer. You can download it for free here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491

When you open SharePoint designer you can connect to the site by copy pasting the url. After you login it will load a lot of assets, including all workflows. Just click the workflow tab to see the workflows that have been created on that site and check if you can find the relevant workflow. These pages from the Microsoft Docs might help you out: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491

Microsoft Flows will not give these type op messages from within SharePoint.